# What is the right data type for calculations in Java

Tags: java, types, math

Should we use double or BigDecimal for calculations in Java?

How much is the overhead in terms of performance for BigDecimal as compared to double?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For a serious financial application BigDecimal is a must.

Depends on how many digits you need you can go with a long and a decimal factor for visualization.

Answer (score 6):

For general floating point calculations, you should use `double`. If you are absolutely sure that you really do need arbitrary precision arithmetic (most applications don't), then you can consider `BigDecimal`.

You will find that `double` will significantly outperform `BigDecimal` (not to mention being easier to work with) for any application where `double` is sufficient precision.

**Update**: You commented on another answer that you want to use this for a *finance related* application. This is one of the areas where you actually should consider using `BigDecimal`, otherwise you may get unexpected rounding effects from `double` calculations. Also, `double` values have limited precision, and you won't be able to accurately keep track of pennies at the same time as millions of dollars.

Answer (score 3):

> How much is the overhead in terms of performance for BigDecimal as compared to double?

A lot.  For example, a multiplication of two doubles is a single machine instruction.  Multiplying two BigDecimals is probably a minimum of 50 machine instructions, and has complexity of `O(N * M)` where `M` and `N` are the number of bytes used to represent the two numbers.

However, if your application requires the calculation to be "decimally correct", then you need to accept the overhead.

However (#2) ... even `BigDecimal` can't do this calculation with *real number* accuracy:

```
       1/3 + 1/3 + 1/3  ->  ?
```

To do that computation precisely you would need to implement a `Rational` type; i.e. a pair of `BigInteger` values ... and some thing to reduce the common factors.

However (#3) ... even a hypothetical `Rational` type won't give you a precise numeric representation for (say) Pi.

Answer (score 1):

As always: it depends.

If you need the precision (even for "small" numbers, when representing amounts for example) go with `BigDecimal`.

In some scientific applications, `double` may be a better choice.

Comment: I need to use it for an finance related application

Comment: Go with BigDecimal, as suggested in other answers.

Answer (score 0):

Even in finance we can't answer without knowing what area. For instance if you were doing currency conversions of $billions, where the conversion rate could be to 5 d.p. you might have problems with double. Whereas for simply adding and subtracting balances you'd be fine.

If you don't need to work in fractions of a cent/penny, maybe an integral type might be more appropriate, again it depends on the size of numbers involved.

Comment: you will get downvoted for "simply adding and subtracting balances you'd be fine".. this is sooo not true.

Comment: If you have objective reasons this is wrong please _post_ rather than make unsubstantiated criticism.